# Counting repeating words with numpy and pandas Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, count

I want to write a code where it outputs the number of repeated values in `a` for each different value. Then I want to make a pandas data sheet to print it. The `sums` code down below does not work how would I be able to make it work and get the Expected Output?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

a = np.array([12,12,12,3,43,43,43,22,1,3,3,43])
uniques = np.unique(a)
sums = np.sum(uniques[:-1]==a[:-1])
```

Expected Output:

```
Value    Repetition Count
1        1
3        3
12       3
22       1
43       4
```

Comment: `sort` the column, then use `groupby().count()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a dataframe `df` based on the array `a`.  Then, use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to get the size/count of unique values, as follows:

```
a = np.array([12,12,12,3,43,43,43,22,1,3,3,43])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': a})

df.groupby('Value').size().reset_index(name='Repetition Count')
```

**Result:**

```
   Value  Repetition Count
0      1                 1
1      3                 3
2     12                 3
3     22                 1
4     43                 4
```

### Edit

If you want also the percentages of counts, you can use:

```
(df.groupby('Value', as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'Repetition Count': ('Value', 'size'), 
           'Percent': ('Value', lambda x: round(x.size/len(a) *100, 2))})
)
```

**Result:**

```
   Value  Repetition Count  Percent
0      1                 1     8.33
1      3                 3    25.00
2     12                 3    25.00
3     22                 1     8.33
4     43                 4    33.33
```

or use [`.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True`

```
pd.Series(a).value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
```

Result:

```
43    33.333333
12    25.000000
3     25.000000
22     8.333333
1      8.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: besides Repetition count can I also place a percentage bar like for the value 43 it has occurred 4/12 so it is 33.3%

Comment: @georgehere  Ok, give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it

Comment: @georgehere  See my edit with the percentages .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html):

```
>>> pd.Series(a).groupby(a).count()
1     1
3     3
12    3
22    1
43    4
dtype: int64
```

Or [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
>>> pd.Series(a).value_counts().sort_index()
1     1
3     3
12    3
22    1
43    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest if you make a pandas dataframe from np.array and then use value_counts().

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['col1'])

print(df.col1.value_counts())
43    4
12    3
3     3
22    1
1     1
```